# factory with asynchronous loading

Tags: actionscript-3, asynchronous, actionscript, factory

I have a singleton factory class, which upon first instantiation loads (asynchronously) some information from a file.

The information is important for the products the factory produces.

My question is related on how to deal with the fact that the factory user might request a product before (but also after) the factory has finished loading the information file.

And most important, do it in an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a pair of solutions, I explain below for future reference.

**Solution number 1:**

Setup 3 methods in the factory: OrderProduct, Produce, PickUpOrder.

The user first call OrderProduct, the factory saves the order and returns an OrderId.

The user setup an event listener on the factory for event "Produced", the callback method to this event, will check if the produced order equals the OrderId the user got from calling OrderProduct, if so call PickUpOrder with the given OrderId, to witch the factory returns the product.

After setting up the listener the user call Produce.

The produce call checks if factory has finished loading, and if so iterates through all the list of orders, producing the product for the given order, and dispatching an event "Produced" with the OrderId for the produced product.

The factory also calls produce after finishing loading the information file.

**Solution number 2:**

If we are lucky that the user knows a product id which is unique, we can twist the first solution to make it more elegant.

We first setup the listener to listen, just as we did in solution 1, but now the listener checks the orderId on the event parameter against the product id, he is gonna request.

Then call OrderProduct, with the product id, which will be used internally by the factory as the OrderId of the first solution.

---

In my opinion Solution 2 is better, since it also supports multithreading, nevertheless I'll happy to discuss critiques to my approaches, or better solutions.

Happy day to everyone!

Comment: Just call you singleton first thing when your app starts. You can even add a listener at this point so your app moves on only when the data is loaded. imo it's way more elegant and efficient.

Comment: Agree with you. But since the factory produces a kind of products which are only needed for a specific part of the application. I didn't even consider it. In my opinion is better to don't load something until you need it.